# AlarmManager won't intent to receiver class

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver

I got problem that my AlarmManager wont intent to receiver class. 
Here is my java code :

Here is alarmManager, i call it from onCreate.

```
static final long TIMETOPAY =  10 * 60 * 1000; // convert to millisecond

..... 
public void showTimerPayment() {

    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    Intent intent = new Intent(PaymentActivity.this, TimerReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PaymentActivity.this, 1, intent, 0);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + TIMETOPAY, alarmIntent);

    Date curDate = new Date();
    long ss = curDate.getTime() + TIMETOPAY;
    SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd  HH:mm:ss");
    String timer = year.format(ss);
    tvTime.setText(timer);
}
```

Here the receiver class :

```
public class TimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,  R.raw.alarm);
      mediaPlayer.start();

   }

}
```

Here is in Manifest

```
<Application
   android:name=".Activity.TimerReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />
</Application>
```

Comment: Is the receiver declared in Manifest.xml file?

Comment: yes..i'll update ..

Comment: please check above

Comment: Why the `android:process=":remote"`?

Comment: i don't know i got it from other reference code ..

Comment: You probably don't need that for what you're trying to achieve. Try to remove that and test it.

Comment: yess that is work..thanks.. d(' ',)

Comment: Using `anroid:process=":remote"` will run your `BroadcastReceiver` in a different OS process. Removing that will run it in the same OS process as the rest of your code.